# How to return first few characters in a string by trimming last 8? (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008

I have a bunch of strings like this:

```
 'ABCD99991000'
 'XYZ79991000'
 'E2493991039'
```

What I really care about is everything before the last 8 characters.  The problem is that the characters I care about at the start of the string are of variable length.  In the above examples, what I'd want to return is:

```
 'ABCD'
 'XYZ'
 'E24'
```

The RIGHT() function would be perfect if I could get it to return everything BEFORE the results.  For example, RIGHT(E2499991039,8) returns the numbers I don't want!  How can I return the variable length strength before the last 8 characters in my query?

SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

```
select substring(column_name, 1, len(column_name)-8)
from table_name
```

Comment: +1 - I believe this deals with cases where the length of the input string is less than the number of chars requested, whereas left does not:
`Invalid length parameter passed to the left function.`

Answer (score 5):

```
declare @str varchar(50)

set @str = 'ABCD99991000'

select LEFT(@str, len(@str) - 8)
```

(No error checking for Len(@str) < 8)

so,

```
select LEFT(colname, LEN(colname) - 8) 
from table_name
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works great.  Didn't think to just subtract from the length!

Answer (score 2):

```
LEFT(E2499991039,LEN(E2499991039)-8)
```

Comment: Thank you, too.  This works great.  Didn't think to just subtract from the length!

Answer (score 2):

```
Left(column, length(column - 8))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
BEGIN
declare @s varchar(16)
select @s = 'abcdefghij'
--
SELECT LEFT(@s, LEN(@s) - 8)
END
```